# How to include square root in a basic calculator

Tags: python, calculator

So I wrote a basic calculator in python:

```
import math
import sys

num1 = float(input("Enter a number "))

operator = input("Enter a operator ")

num2 = float(input("Enter a second number "))
if operator == '+':
    print (num1) + (num2)
elif operator == '-':
    print(num1 - num2)
elif operator == '*':
    print(num1 * num2)
elif operator == '/':
    print(num1 / num2)

elif operator == "sqrt":
        print(math.sqrt(num1))

else:
    print("Unknown operator")
```

I want to make the **square root command** function so that when I choose **num1** and the square root operator it skips the rest and gives me the results directly. Instead of needing to also write out **num2**.

Comment: After getting the operator, just check if it's the square root operator, and if so, skip getting num2.

Comment: If you want to check the operator before `num2` input, then why write the condition after that input?

Comment: Small comment: There's an error in the following line:  "print (num1) + (num2)" - that needs to be "print (num1 + num2)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a function so you can `return` before asking for `num2` if appropriate:

```
import math

def calc():
    num1 = float(input("Enter a number "))
    operator = input("Enter a operator ")

    if operator == "sqrt":
        print(math.sqrt(num1))
        return

    num2 = float(input("Enter a second number "))
    if operator == '+':
        print (num1) + (num2)
    elif operator == '-':
        print(num1 - num2)
    elif operator == '*':
        print(num1 * num2)
    elif operator == '/':
        print(num1 / num2)


calc()
```

Other unary operations can simply be added as `elif`s under the one for `sqrt`.

Another approach might be to put your operators into dicts according to the number of operands:

```
import math

unary_ops = {
    "sqrt": math.sqrt,
}
binary_ops = {
    "*": float.__add__,
    "-": float.__sub__,
    "*": float.__mul__,
    "/": float.__truediv__,
}

num1 = float(input("Enter a number "))
operator = input("Enter a operator ")
if operator in unary_ops:
    print(unary_ops[operator](num1))
elif operator in binary_ops:
    num2 = float(input("Enter a second number "))
    print(binary_ops[operator](num1, num2))
else:
    print(f"Sorry, I don't know how to '{operator}'.")
```

Comment: I assume a different solution would do `num1 **= 0.5` rather than print it